# Android Saving Edittext content to SharedPreferences and Reading it back

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, sharedpreferences

In my xml i have an edittext element like this

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/hrvalue"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="64"
android:textSize="18sp">
</EditText>
```

in my configuration class i want to read the value of the edittext and save it to a variable.
In the edittext box the user will be inputting a number integer.
I have wrote the following code

```
SharedPreferences prefs = self.getSharedPreferences("prefs", 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor edit = prefs.edit();
EditText hrvalue = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.hrvalue);
edit.putString("hrvalue"+appWidgetId,hrvalue.getText().toString());
edit.commit();
```

Could i read the value in the edittext box as integer?

Now I want to read the value as integer in my other class but i don't know how to do it.
The sharedpreferences key,value pairs is a bit confusing for me.
I wrote

```
int hrvalue=prefs.getInt("hrvalue"+appWidgetId,1);
```

Is this correct? Is that the correct way of reading from an edittext and adding it to sharedpreferences?Where is the value of an edittextbox stored?
I had success with checkbox but not yet with edittext.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `putInt` instead of `putString` if you want to store an int. See [this documention.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html)